# Mongoose and Kue - Node.js - Object passed has no method save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request, mongoose, kue

I'm using mongoose and Kue for the Flow control. I pass an object retrieved from the database to Kue. When the job get processed, the object hasn't anymore some functions, like .save() & others.

```
  jobs.process('process', 5, function(job, done) {
        var url = job.data.url;
        var objo = job.data.comp;

        request({uri:url, json:true}, function(err, res, body) {
            objo.meta = body;

            // Here it throw an error that save is note defined
            // TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
            objo.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                console.log('Saved data for ' + objo.title);
                done();
            });
        });
    });


    var q = db.Entity.find({}).sort('_id', 1).limit(10);

    q.execFind(function(err, docs) {
        docs.forEach(function(objo) {

            jobs.create('process', {
                comp : objo,
                url : 'http://example.com/' + encodeURIComponent(objo.permalink) + '.js'
            }).save();
        })
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Kue doesn't save the object entirely, it just saves the value of calling `JSON.stringify()` on it. You'll need to pass the id of the object in, and grab the mongoose representation back out of the database in your worker.